# Why is this regex matching when tested, but not in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have a regex that I need to identify if certain function types are in a file. Like this:

```
$stringsetexists = grep {/void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>;
```

This is run from a perl file, trying to match functions like the following in a .cpp file:

```
void setChanName(const std::string & chanName)
void setChanNameFont(const std::string & font)
void setOSDMessage(const std::string & osdMessage)
void setOSDMessageFont(const std::string & font)
```

When I run the regex (inputted as: `void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string`   ) through a regex tester such as [www.regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/), all of these match (yes, I know they only match through the end of "string". That's what I want).

However, when I run the above command in a perl script, it finds no matches. I know the script is opening the file properly, so that's not the issue. And I know other regexs in the perl script work. What is the problem?

**EDIT**: Confounding the issue, the following regex:

```
 $stringsetexists = grep {/inline void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>;
```

works just fine when run on a file that contains a line like the following:

```
 inline void setIPv6Address(const std::string & ipv6Address)
```

(not the ONLY difference in the regexes is the addition of "inline " before "void". And the ONLY difference in the file is the addition of "inline " before "void".

**EDIT 2**: Expanding on what I already put, the relevant block of code is here:

```
open $fh, "<", $file;
$stringsetexists = grep {/inline void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>; #this works for all files that contain "inline void"
if ($file eq "OSDSettings.h") #I know this part runs, because the print statement inside properly prints out that it is in OSDSettings.h
{
    $stringsetexists = grep {/void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>;
    print $file." opened: ".$stringsetexists."\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Perl script?

Comment: `[s|S]`  - I'm fairly sure you're not trying to match a literal pipe there, use `[sS]`.  `[\w]` also doesn't need brackets.  This (probably) won't fix your problem, but - you know.

Comment: @RohitJain - the perl script is some 800+ lines long. It was working perfectly before I added this line. So the problem is not in the script

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - thanks. It did not fix my problem

Comment: @iamthesgt. I mean just the part where you are performing the match operation with the regex. The input string, and your output which you get.

Comment: The regex matches those strings, so that's not your problem. You need to add more information, or this question cannot be answered. Make an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @RohitJain - I just run `if ($stringsetexists != 0){ #code here never executes }`. I also just have the value of `$stringsetexists` printed out, but it is zero.

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your code as well. That might give you the solution right away.

Comment: @RohitJain - it's in the question. The first line is where I get `$stringsetexists`. The input string is another file, which contains the functions I showed.

Comment: @TLP - Thanks, they were already in there

Comment: @TLP - Alright. I said they did match in the regex tester. I guess I should have said I don't think they match. I added a more concise example of the code.

Comment: @iamthesgt Do you use those two greps at the same time? (Note that you should check the return value of `open`, but that error wouldnt be silent here, so that's not it). If you use `<$fh>` twice in list context, it will be exhausted the second time.

Comment: @TLP - bam. That was it. Thank you for your help. I'm sorry I didn't post enough examples at first.

Comment: Clarifying, I simply needed to `close ($fh);` then `open $fh, "<", $file` in between the grep and the if

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewind or re-open `$fh` before your second `grep`.

This code:

```
grep { ... } <$fh>
```

will *exhaust* `$fh`, reading all lines in the file.  When you next call `grep { ... } <$fh>`, there are no more lines to match because `$fh` is at end-of-file.

Comment: Bingo! The first `<$fh>` reads remainder of the file, leaving nothing for the second `<$fh>` to read. Better yet, load the file into a variable. The whole file is loaded into memory by the existing code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/ldgWVTsm

Looks like it works to me, but notice that you want to loop through your file, rather than place your filehandle (`<$fh>`) at the end.

***Note:** this should be a comment and not an answer, but the answer is you have no problem.*

---

Based on comments and other answer, I've updated the example to show how you may reuse a filehandle.  However, there are better more efficient ways to do this, so this is purely for example:

http://codepad.org/jfxt1YOd

```
use strict;

my $fh       = *DATA;            # set the filehandle
my $pos      = tell $fh;         # store file pos

## Positive Matches

my @matched  = grep {/void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>;

print "Found: " . @matched . "\n";
print "Matches:\n @matched";


# Reset the position to use again
seek $fh, $pos, 0;

## Negative Matches

my @not_matched = grep {$_ !~ /void [s|S]et[\w]+\(\s*.*string/} <$fh>;

print "Found: " . @not_matched . "\n";
print "Not Matched:\n @not_matched";

__DATA__
viod setChanName(const std::string & chanName)     # Notice the misspelling
void setChanName(const std::string & chanName)
void setChanNameFont(const std::string & font)
void setOSDMessage(const std::string & osdMessage)
void setOSDMessageFont(const std::string & font)
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by looping through the file?

Comment: the issue is probably in your assignment of your `$fh`, so it's easier to loop through line by line `while(<FILEHANDLE>){...}` to help debug.

Comment: I think that's it, I closed the file and re-opened it right before the grep. I believe the problem was that grep had reached the end of the file on the previous grep, and so when I tried to grep, there was nothing left to look for

Comment: @iamthesgt I updated the answer.  I think your final edit was most helpful -- I didn't realize you were calling the same file handle twice.  As stated in my answer, the code above is not the most efficient, but is more effective for demonstration/learning.